# Steps for redistricting using ArcGIS Desktop or Open Source GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, open-source-gis, redistricting

I have been struggling with how to redistrict in ArcGIS Desktop so can anyone put me through the necessary steps, data, extensions, to perform this operation.

More so, is there any Open Source GIS that can perform this task?

Comment: Welcome to our site! It will help to ask a more focused question--one that reflects the specific problems you are having and shares with us the efforts you have already made towards resolving them.  For more help, please consult our [faq]. By the way, it will help to toggle your caps-lock key back: all caps is considered a form of SHOUTING and tends to discourage people from reading or answering your question.

Answer (score 3):

ESRI offers two products to support redistricting (as in drawing boundaries for election districts). The web-based product is described [here](http://www.esri.com/software/redistricting).
There's also an add-on version that is described [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/districting). As best as I can tell, the add-on is free and will work on versions 9.0 forward. Documentation and a tutorial are [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/redistricting/pdf/Districting_for_ArcGIS_Help.pdf). This add-on appears to be designed to help create district maps in the US, as one of the key inputs is population data. I have no idea how useful this add-on would be in another country.

I have only limited exposure to redistricting, but it is a complex process in that there are many overlapping and conflicting goals in designing districts, depending on the designer's objectives. Thus, Democrats create different district maps from Republicans.

Answer (score 3):

Azavea has released a web-based, open source software for collaborative redistricting called [DistrictBuilder](http://www.azavea.com/products/districtbuilder/). You might want to [try it out](http://www.publicmapping.org/resources/software/demo).

[image]

As for learning about redistricting, you might want to read [A Citizen's Guide to Redistricting](http://www.brennancenter.org/content/resource/a_citizens_guide_to_redistricting_2010_edition/).

[image]